# I am attempting to use tensorflow micro speech for arduino portenta and I am getting compiling errors

Tags: tensorflow, arduino

Below is the errors I am getting

Compiling debug version of 'micro_speech' for 'Arduino Portenta H7 (M7 core)'

C_API_~1.C: In function void TfLiteTensorRealloc(size_t, TfLiteTensor*)

C_API_~1.C: 139:30: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
tensor->data.raw = malloc(num_bytes)

```
C_API_~1.C: 141:31: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
tensor->data.raw = realloc(tensor->data.raw, num_bytes)
~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~1.C: In function uint32_t* FilterbankSqrt(FilterbankState*, int)

FILTER~1.C: 121:37: error: invalid conversion from 'uint64_t* {aka long long unsigned int*}' to 'const int64_t* {aka const long long int*}' [-fpermissive]
const int64_t* work = state->work + 1
~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~

FILTER~2.C: In function int FilterbankPopulateState(const FilterbankConfig*, FilterbankState*, int, int)

FILTER~2.C: 69:13: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*state->channel_frequency_starts))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 71:13: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*state->channel_weight_starts))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 73:13: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*state->channel_widths))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 74:23: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'uint64_t* {aka long long unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->work = malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*state->work))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 77:13: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'float*' [-fpermissive]
malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*center_mel_freqs))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 79:13: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*actual_channel_starts))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 81:13: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
malloc(num_channels_plus_1 * sizeof(*actual_channel_widths))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 163:26: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->weights = calloc(weight_index_start, sizeof(*state->weights))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FILTER~2.C: 164:28: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->unweights = calloc(weight_index_start, sizeof(*state->unweights))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

NOISE_~1.C: In function int NoiseReductionPopulateState(const NoiseReductionConfig*, NoiseReductionState*, int)

NOISE_~1.C: 35:27: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'uint32_t* {aka long unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->estimate = calloc(state->num_channels, sizeof(*state->estimate))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

PCAN_G~2.C: In function int PcanGainControlPopulateState(const PcanGainControlConfig*, PcanGainControlState*, uint32_t*, int, uint16_t, int32_t)

PCAN_G~2.C: 55:27: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->gain_lut = malloc(kWideDynamicFunctionLUTSize * sizeof(int16_t))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

WINDOW~1.C: In function int WindowPopulateState(const WindowConfig*, WindowState*, int)

WINDOW~1.C: 39:31: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->coefficients = malloc(state->size * sizeof(*state->coefficients))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

WINDOW~1.C: 56:24: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->input = malloc(state->size * sizeof(*state->input))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

WINDOW~1.C: 62:25: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int16_t* {aka short int*}' [-fpermissive]
state->output = malloc(state->size * sizeof(*state->output))
~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error compiling libraries
Debug build failed for project 'micro_speech'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I do not understand the errors and what is the problem with compiling the libraries?  The program I am trying to run is the micro speech example but it appears I am getting the same error with all the examples in the tensorflowlite library for arduino. Is there a work around to get the program compiled and running?